# How do I center my Google Map Android application to provided coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, xamarin

I need to find out how can I move my android googlemap programmatically. I got the map working, but now i need to add the functionality of centering the map to specific coordinates given to me by the google geocoder httprequest. I got the coordinates out of the response from google, but I have not found any way to actually move my map to said point.

I'm mostly getting in trouble with the reference assemblies. I'm using Xamarin C# and it seems that all the tutorials and examples are in Java and the calls for stuff are totally different and need stuff that are not here in C#.

- How do I get my map to move to a desired location on the map?
- And how do I place a marker on that point?

Also please add the names of any necessary reference assemblies on your answer so I'll know what to add/use.

Thank you

.

Here's my relevant code:

MapsActivity.cs

```
public class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity {
    Query q;
    int latE6, lonE6;
    LatLng coordinates;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Map);

        EditText sText = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.et_location);
        Button fButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btn_find);
        fButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
            q = new Query(sText.Text);
            q.CreateQuery();
            var result = q.ResponseFromGoogle.results.Find (item => item.geometry.location.lat.ToString("F") != null);
            sText.Text = result.geometry.location.lat.ToString("F") + " " + result.geometry.location.lat.ToString("F");

            coordinates = new LatLng(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
        };
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="IgluHarkka2.IgluHarkka2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. This key will not work for you.-->
    <!-- See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_btn_find"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/hnt_et_location"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_find" />
</RelativeLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#changing_a_maps_view) are a summery of how you change how the map is shown. The part under Change Camera position will help tou.

Comment: Okay fair enough. I think I understand that. But I have a problem that I don't know how to get my mapfragment programmatically. I've seen stuff like mMap = getMap();, but that's not C# or at least does not work with my current references. How should I call my mapfragment from my MapsActivity.cs?

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

I can't call this or anything like this. I can create a FragmentManager fragmenManager. But there is no method getFragmentManager();. What to do?